# Debugging PHP in Dreamweaver CS5

Tags: php, debugging, dreamweaver

is there an extension for dreamweaver cs5 that can support debugging?

I know there are other IDE's like netbeans that can accomplish that task, but I also do html/js and netbeans isn't particularly good for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I beg to differ. Those IDEs are, in fact, *way* better at *anything* regarding HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

I strongly recommend [Zend Studio](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/index2?src=hpb) ($299) or [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt) (free). [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) is supposed to be an excellent IDE as well (just that I'm not familiar with it).

Also, I use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) to debug my JavaScripts. It's amazing.  Actually, many modern browsers come equipped with JavaScript debugging tools, surprisingly including Internet Explorer (I think only version 8 and above but IE7 might have it too...I don't remember).

Comment: You can use the [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359) if you must fix something for IE. It's pretty good actually, you can even use breakpoints in JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah! That's what I was thinking of but I couldn't remember. And yeah you're right, it's actually pretty good.

Comment: how can you say netbeans is even close to dreamweaver in html/css/..

it only allows php projects created and
 every time you want to do cross-browser testing, you have to go into the options and switch the browser configuration. Those are just two of many problems Netbeans has with html/css.

Comment: Because virtually _anything_ is better than Dreamweaver for web development. Dreamweaver should _never_ be used for mission-critical projects. In my opinion it's more of a "I've never seen HTML before and I'm working on a high school project" sort of thing.

Comment: you've clearly haven't worked with dreamweaver before then. Check out CS5. I'm not talking about the useless drag and drop stuff in the design view dreamweaver has because there is more to that. You have much better project management, cross browser testing options and an ftp where you can actually see the files ( theres no remote view in the netbeans ftp). So if you think dreamweaver is just some drag and drop design tool, you're wrong my friend. There is infact a code view.

Comment: Regarding your original post, I will give zend studio a try; it seems like a pretty full blown ide. Thanks :)

Comment: :) You're welcome! And I will check out CS5 just to humor you. Although I'm pretty sure my opinion of it won't change _much_. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend Aptana Studio http://aptana.com/
I am using it for along long time and it helped me alot
also use google chrome debugger by clicking F12 it is the best html/js debugger

Comment: I have this one too, but I don't know why they make you use their internal server for previewing your files. Also setting up your run configurations for every project is a bit of a drag.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use **TSW WebCoder**

In **TSW WebCoder** go to the **Debug menu** and **select Setup debugging**. You will be presented with a wizard, which will walk you though the entire process of setting up debugging on your machine.